# Get the first property of an object with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

We are using PowerShell's `Invoke-RestMethod` to monitor re-index tasks running in ElasticSearch. Their output format is a bit quirky and, instead of arrays `[...]` they sadly opted for objects `{...}` so it looks like this:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "fooVSmai0c0uR_Co7g": {...},
        "barVSmai0c0uR_B1Fd": {...}
        ...
}
```

We want to get access to the first object in the list into `$taskRunning` and our current code seems a bit clunky. Is there a more elegant way?

```
$tasks = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://elasticsearch:9200/_tasks?detailed=true&actions=*reindex"
$task1 = $tasks.nodes.PSObject.Properties | Select -First 1
if ($task1 -eq $null) {"No reindex tasks running!"; return}
$TaskId = $task1.Name
$taskRunning = $tasks.nodes.$($TaskId)
```

Comment: `$tasks = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri | ConvertFrom-Json` to get it into a native powershell object, then it becomes much easier.

Comment: No, that's failing with "Invalid JSON primitive" because `ConvertFrom-Json` expects a string and `Invoke-RestMethod` is returning an object. I tried it with `Invoke-WebRequest` and it succeeds but the resulting object (viewed with `ConvertTo-Json`) is still the same (no array). :-(

Comment: The json you're getting doesn't have an array... You'll want to do something like `$tasks.nodes.Keys()` and parse through the objects that way.